# Using Standard Resistance Values, what are the combinations of 2 resistors in series or parallel to achieve a non standard resistance?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, combinations

I am trying to figure out an algorithm to get a list of 2 resistances either in parallel or series that gives an equivalent resistance close to the desired non-standard resistance.

I am given a list of all the standard resistances in the series like E12,E24 etc. I am also given a desired resistance. I want to calculate a list of configurations for $R_1$ and $R_2$ to get a resistance within 1% of my desired resistance.

I thought of the bounds for series, $R_1$ and $R_2$ have to be < $R_{desired}$ and either $R_1$ or $R_2$ have to be > $\frac{R_{desired}}{2}$ so that they can add up to equal $R_{desired}$.

I'm having problems with parallel combinations though, I am not sure what the bound for $R_1$ and $R_2$ have to be if in parallel so that I can find the combinations. The problem with parallel is to get the combination of 2 parallel resistances you need to do $\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} = \frac{1}{R_{desired}}$ meaning that $R_1$ and $R_2$ can be > than $R_{desired}$.

If anyone can help me with this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Exhaustive search (which will take negligible time, even with thousands of candidate values).

Comment: I agree with @DavidG.Stork that an exhaustive search is probably efficient enough, but if you don't like that: If you have a solution you like for resistances in series, can't you turn your "resistances in parallel" question into a "conductances in series" question and re-use the same solution?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I just thought of the same thing, using conductance and using the same method as series. Thank you very much

Comment: @momo: The joke about mathematicians is that they always want to be "reducing it to a previously solved problem". As you can see, the idea is useful and the joke is true.

Comment: @momo: One thing you need to beware of is that being within 1% in conductance does not guarantee being within 1% of resistance. I'm assuming you'll find the two closest conductances, one above and once below, and convert them back to resistance before deciding which is better.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC thanks for the heads up. Yes I will take that in to account.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $R_1\le R_2$ then $\frac 1{R_1}\ge\frac 1{R_2}$ and $\frac 2{R_2}\le\frac 1{R_d}\le\frac 2{R_1}$ and can only estimate $R_1\le 2R_d\le R_2$